# psql does not show relations, tables. sample "select 2+2;" returns nothing

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin

psql does not show relations, tables. 
even sample `select 2+2;` returns nothing

tried with `psql (9.5.19, server 9.6.3)` and
`psql (11.7 (Ubuntu 11.7-2.pgdg18.04+1), server 9.6.3)`

PgAdmin works fine with that server. I can see/browse all data

It all started suddenly. Broken on all client boxes. I am no db owner, so I don't know  if they changed some server config values.

What could be the case?

P.S. Guess I can use some other clients or something like JDBC if there is no solution, but this issue still puzzles me

Comment: this might be one of the few cases where a screenshot of your `psql` invocation and output might help

Comment: Does this still happen if you run `psql -X ...`?

Comment: oh ffs, I'm so stupid, thank you. for the mention of invocation.
I was using -o path_to_csv and forgot about it. If you'll answer this, I'll accept the answer